# Failed to insert data into Acces DB

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, dataset

I try to insert some data in an Acces database using ADO.Net, it runs through all of my code without giving errors. But if I go look in my database, I see nothing is in the table.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Heres the code in run in my FormMain:

```
BLAfbeelding blAfbeelding = new BLAfbeelding();
blAfbeelding.InsertAfbeelding(new AfbeeldingConverter().imageToByteArray(paint.Tekening), gebruiker.Id, openbaar, naam);
```

This is the code in my BLL class:

```
public void InsertAfbeelding(byte[] afbeelding, int gebruikerId, bool openbaar, string naam)
{
   adapter.InsertAfbeelding(afbeelding, gebruikerId, openbaar, naam);
}
```

and this is my SQL query in my dataset:

```
INSERT INTO `Afbeelding` (`Afbeelding`, `GebruikerId`, `Openbaar`, `Naam`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Could you post the whole method that try to insert? Access doesn't like the backticks, Just remove them and if there are no other problems it should work

Comment: did you add the corresponding parameters. Are you not getting any exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the folders under your project. Most likely you have an original (source)  db-file in the main project folder and a working copy in `Bin\Debug`. You insert in the second and then look in the first. Also, the working copy is easily overwritten.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO Afbeelding (Afbeelding, GebruikerId, Openbaar, Naam) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
```